# Flash avb_custom_key using EDL

Tags: rooting, rom-flashing, custom-roms, bootloader, dm-verity

As documented [here](https://source.android.com/docs/security/features/verifiedboot/device-state?authuser=2), many bootloaders will allow flashing a custom verity key to the avb_custom_key partition using fastboot. This then allows a custom chain of trust so the device will boot a custom ROM.

I have a phone which has a locked bootloader so I cannot flash the avb_custom_key using fastboot. But, I do have Qualcomm EDL mode access with a firehose loader.

Does anyone know if there is any way to use EDL to flash avb_custom_key? It does not show as a partition in the GPT. Google calls it a virtual partition. I don't know what that means.

Comment: I found more more information about avb_custom_key [here](https://blog.csdn.net/dongyi1988/article/details/103995737). It seems like for devices with secure boot, avb_custom_key is stored in the security area (RPMB area) of the emmc. So, probably EDL cannot access it.

Comment: the site you linked is a valuable ressource, but hard to translate. if I got it right, what you want requires modified bootloader (abl.mbn) which is, due the nature of closed source, high hacking level. consider writing up an answer, sounds quite interesting.

Comment: Google translate works well. I can't modify the bootloader since secure boot is enabled, so the bootloader needs to be OEM signed. That's why I was hoping there was some way to do it with EDL directly.

Comment: just curious about the device model, maybe there exist exploit to unlock bootloader